# VBA Split Range Expression

Tags: excel, vba, range

Assuming I have some cells with Expressions filled like this :

```
Dim Sample1 As String
Sample1 = "1-4,5+6,9,12-20"
Dim Sample2 As String
Sample2 = "1-7,8,30,20+21,45"
Dim Sample3 As String
Sample3 = "1-7,8,11-17"
```

What's the best way to convert this expression into an array which contains the specified numbers?
So e.g for Sample1 the array for this expression should conmtain the values :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

My first attempt would be to split the expression by commas and then try to figure out whats left and right from the "-" and the "+" but maybe there is a better way?
Can you give me some advice how to do this best?

Comment: For the `+` symbol, just replace it with a `,`. (If I understand your example correctly, it is the same thing basically.) I'd handle the `-` symbol before splitting.

Comment: That's *too broad*. You need to show us what you've tried and how it's failing, as opposed to asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace any `-` with `+` so they all react the same to a second nested split.

```
Option Explicit

Function udf_All_Nums(str As String, Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim tmp As String, val As Variant, vals As Variant
    Dim a As Long, i As Long

    vals = Split(str, Chr(44))
    For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        vals(a) = Replace(vals(a), Chr(45), Chr(43))
        val = Split(vals(a), Chr(43))
        For i = val(LBound(val)) To val(UBound(val))
            tmp = tmp & delim & i
        Next i
    Next a

    udf_All_Nums = Mid(tmp, Len(delim) + 1) 'Join(vals, delim)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hey that's exactly what I meant ! Thanks !